# What is the difference between managed mode and promiscuous mode?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have heard these two terms but I do not know the difference between them. Are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different. Managed mode is for pretty much normal WiFi connections (a client connecting to an access point). Managed mode will ignore frames that go to a different MAC address. Promiscuous mode will process them.

Comment: Does that mean promiscuos mode is like monitor mode but in the the range when I have been connected to the specific AP?

Comment: Yes, promiscuous mode only captures from the network you are connected to. See [What is the difference between Promiscuous and Monitor Mode in Wireless Networks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36997) for more.

Comment: And depending on drivers can also inject packets in promiscuous mode. +1